# Expected value of random variable with random parameter

Tags: r, expected-value, exponential-distribution, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to answer a question about expectations. Let's say I have a random variable, $X$, which is distributed $Expo(\lambda)$. Now assume that $\lambda$ is also an R.V. and is distributed $Expo(5)$. How do I find $E(X)$? Assume that I don't need to do this analytically, I can use the `integrate` command in `R`, for instance. I believe I should be using Adam's Law, but I'm not sure. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a `self-study` question. Can you explain where you have problem with using Adam's Law?

Comment: I understand the Adam's Law part of it I think (based on Siong's answer below). I'm unsure of how to actually integrate it in R.

Comment: Why would you want to find a numerical approximation when you can get the exact answer?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
E[X] &= \int_0^\infty E[X|\lambda]f(\lambda)  \, d\lambda \\
&= \int_0^\infty E[X|\lambda](5)\exp(-5\lambda) \, d\lambda
\end{align}

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Hint: it is something huge.

- Reading on [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) might help you.